# Android Studio Run/Debug configuration error: Module not specified

Tags: android, android-studio, module, gradle

I am getting a 'Module not specified' error in my run config. I have no module showing in the drop down yet I can see my module no probs. The issue came about when I refactored my module name, changed the settings.gradle to new name.

Now when I go to project structure and select my module nothing shows in the screen, not even an error.

I'm not 100% sure, but the icon beside my module looks like a folder with a cup and not a folder with a phone.

My exact steps -

1. Open in Android view
2. Refactor directory name
3. refactor module name
4. change settings.gradle contents: name to new name

Answer (score 57, accepted):

never mind, i changed the name in settings.gradle and synced and then changed it back and synced again and it inexplicably worked this time.

Comment: Can you specify where settings.gradle

Comment: Just resyncing  did it for me.

Comment: I syced the gradle. Didn't change anything. Now its working.

Comment: I had the same thing but for me the reason was that the sync stopped working. closing android studio and deleting .idea and .gradle seams to solve the problem.

Comment: Voted down as this answer is purely worded an unclear.

Comment: Running a sync again did the job for me.

Comment: This may help someone in the future too. Coming from a React Native standpoint, open Android Studio, the root project folder should be the "android" folder, not the root of your react native project. Took me a bit to realize this. After I figured that out, following Fearghal's steps fixed the rest.

Answer (score 505):

### Resync your project gradle files to add the `app` module through Gradle

1. In the root folder of your project, open the `settings.gradle` file for editing.
2. Cut line `include ':app'` from the file.
3. On Android Studio, click on the `File` Menu, and select `Sync Project  with Gradle files`.
4. After synchronisation, paste back line `include ':app'` to the `settings.gradle` file.
5. Re-run `Sync Project with Gradle files` again.

Comment: Up voted this one as it gave specific steps to fix, rather than general directions.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! Can you or somebody else explain why it works and/or why it's sometimes necessary?

Comment: I thought JetBrains had some brains. Are they turning Android Studio into Eclipse? Thanks @eLi, the solutions works great!!!

Comment: Best answer I have seen yet on this subject... worked like a charm... Thanks

Comment: That is incredible useful. How is it possible that Android Studio has such a big flaw?

Comment: Why does this work though? Worked fine on my end, but interested in knowing why it works.

Comment: It works! But how did you even discover this?!

Comment: Worked like a Magic! Cheers!

Comment: Is this a feature of Android Studio?

Comment: When I remove `include ':app'` "Project directory '/home/phil/Desktop/NATIV/app' is not part of the build defined by settings file"

Comment: This is incredible. I was stuck as my instrumentation test were not getting any , run option . this has saved me. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 23):

This issue also may happen when you just installed **new Android studio** and importing some project, in the new Android studio only the latest sdk is downloaded(for example currently the latest is 30) and if your project `target sdk` is 29 you will not see your `module` in `run configuring` dialog.

So download the sdk that your app is targeted, then run `Sync project with gradle files`.

[image]

Comment: This is what worked for me after updating my version of Android Studio

Comment: This ended up working for me. After downloading the sdk, go to settings.gradle file change and sync. and finally change it back to `include ':app'`

Answer (score 18):

Try to delete the app.iml in your project directory and restart android studio

Comment: Also, just do this if Android Studio doesn't "rebuild" your project after you click on `Run > Rebuild Project`.

Answer (score 14):

You have 3 ways:

1. Clean Project in Android Studio menu

**Build -> Clean Project and use Build -> Rebuild**

---

2. Remove all the modules in `settings.gradle`

- Open `settings.gradle` project
- Remove `include ':app'` and other modules
- Sync gradle
- Add `include ':app'` and other modules
- Sync gradle again

---

3. Remove all code in gradle.properties

- Open `gradle.properties` project
- Remove all code

  `org.gradle.daemon=true`

  `org.gradle.configureondemand=true`

  `org.gradle.parallel=true`

  `android.enableBuildCache=true`
- Sync gradle
- Add code again
- Sync gradle again

Comment: In my case When I change package name it's changed in setting.gradle

Answer (score 9):

check your `build.gradle` file and make sure that use `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`
 istead of 
`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

it worked for me

Comment: Yes but what if your module really is a  'com.android.library' and you're writing an activity beneath androidTest to test it? That's what JW does here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/tree/master/rxbinding-swiperefreshlayout/src/androidTest. There must be a way to run...

Answer (score 8):

None of the existing answers worked in my case (Android studio 3.5.0). I had to

1. close all android studio projects
2. remove the project from the recent projects in android studio wizard
3. restart android studio
4. use **import option** (Import project- Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc) instead of open an existing project AS project
5. File -> Sync project with gradle files

Answer (score 6):

I realized following line was missing in `settings.gradle` file

```
include ':app'
```

make sure you include ":app" module

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this because I'm developing a library, and every now and then want to run it as an application.

From app/build.gradle, check that you have `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` instead of `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.

You should also have this in app/build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your_company.your_application"
        ...
}
```

Finally run Gradle sync.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't find your settings.gradle file in your project directory

1. Add settings.gradle file
2. Add include ':app' inside the settings.gradle file
3. Rebuild or sync your project

Your app module should appear in your configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after update on Android Studio 3.2.1 I had to re-import project, after that everything works

Answer (score 3):

**I would like to add some more information while I was facing this issue:**

Ref: Answer from @Eli:

> 1. Cut line include '`:app`' from the file.
> 2. On Android Studio, click on the File Menu, and select Sync Project
>    with Gradle files.
> 3. After synchronisation, paste back line include ':app' to the settings.gradle file.
> 4. Re-run Sync Project with Gradle files again.

So, let's follow the instruction and try to keep one thing in mind, that what is showing in your build configuration. Make sure you are seeing the name of your configuration `app` like the image below:
[image]
If you are seeing anything else, then the steps mentioned by @Eli (the most accepted answer) will not work.

**An alternative Solution**
If you have a different name on the **Run/Debug Configurations** window and the above process is not working, please change the config name to '`app`'

> then -> hit **Apply** -> then **Ok**.

After that follow this:-

> **File**->**Sync project with gradle files** (if needed).

Now check the issue will be resolved hopefully. I have faced this issue and I think it might help others as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had to select "Use classpath of module:" drop down option and choose my module.

Comment: this was only thing which helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to open an old GitHub project with the latest android studio that's why got this error. I tried almost all the way that mentions in this post but none of them is work.

In my case, I update my Gradle version with my latest project, and the issue resolved. Use your latest Gradle version to resolve the issue.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the project doesn't load your sdk version.
so manually change the this in your build.gradle file module level to your own sdk version

1. compileSdkVersion 28
2. buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
3. targetSdkVersion 28

now re-sync the your project.

Answer (score 2):

If no solution works then make sure that you **opened the project from the right directory**

For example, when I opened the project from *app* folder and from the *root*
I got

> Module not specified

error, but when I opened it from **todoapp** the error had gone

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks Islam Ahmed, I found this out myself and came here to add it if needed.
In my case I opened the root folder of a fresh repo clone using Android Studio project launcher, instead of clicking down to where the app is. Wasted 30 minutes on it this morning and I feel slightly better that I'm not the only one to do this :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your minsdkversion, compilesdkversion and targetsdkversion and ensure that you installed all those from **Tools -> SDKManager** in Android Studio.

e.g if your targetsdkversion is 30 and minsdkversion is 28, ensure that you installed 28, 29, 30 sdks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove from app gradle this code

```
android{
    defaultConfig.applicationId="com.storiebox"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are currently recommending AS 3.3 for exercises.

These settings will work in the current 3.3 beta version with two small changes to your project:

In build.gradle (Project), change gradle version to 3.3.0-rc02

In menu go to File -> Project Structure. There you can change the gradle version to 4.10.0

Answer (score 0):

in my case, when I added Fragment I git this error.

When I opened THe app `build.gradle` I saw `id("kotlin-android")` this plugin in plugins.

just remove it!

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your project and and invalidate caches / restart. After that your project might be fixed.

This solution works for me.

Comment: "Worked for me" answers are not encouraged. Please try improving this by adding info on how to invalidate the cache and restart.

Answer (score 0):

**For me the issue and solution:**

- I am using Webrtc library module in my android project. I had updated the compile and targeted sdk version in my gradle for only app module have havent for the webrtc library gradle.
- Go to SDK Manager and confirm if the sdk version is installed (completely and not partially).
- After above steps Invalidate & Restart app.
- In project folder on your windows explorer within your project delete the .idea folder.

**Note:** Make sure to update your gradle for all module other than app module as well.

Answer (score 0):

For my scenario, the fix was simpler. I had accidentally opened my project in Android Studio one folder too high, so it wasn't finding settings.gradle and build.gradle in the root project folder. Once I realized that and opened from the root of my project instead, the Run/Debug configuration came back.

Answer (score 0):

In my 1st case, There was **no internet connectivity** while I opened the project. After the internet connectivity is back, we just resync the gradle and it works.

In my 2nd case, Also, there may be an issue with the **firewall**. If there are any firewall restrictions, It could not work. After disabling firewall restrictions and resyncing the gradle, it worked well.

Answer (score -1):

Run the app, it will show '`Edit Configuration`' window.
Under `Module` - select the app (it would be `<no module>` ).

Then select the activity (under `Launch Options`)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If all above solution doesn't work then do try this solution, because in my case none of the above solution were working.
I too was facing this problem and after 5 hour of hard work I am able to tell you a solution.
If you are cloning project using git the I would recommend you to directly clone project using android studio.
It worked for me.