# Android Studio Config Broken

Tags: java, android

When I started Android Studio I saw that the 'Play' Button was disabled (Gray Color).

I found out that it's a Problem of my Debug Configuration

I clicked on the Edit Config button , I had **none** ...

I can't find any guide of how to create new Configuration

Even Android Studio's website says :

> - Modify the configuration, as needed.*

Ok... How do you edit it? And what do you edit ?

Maybe this is something realted ? :

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.discopc.yubismart"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need to know about creating and editing Run/Debug configurations are clearly explained in the following official page:

- [Create and Edit Run/Debug Configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html)

These answers can be helpful too:

- [Android Studio: Module won't show up in "Edit Configuration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368748/android-studio-module-wont-show-up-in-edit-configuration)
- [Android Studio Run/Debug configuration error: Module not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087882/android-studio-run-debug-configuration-error-module-not-specified)
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-an-android-run-debug-configuration.html

Comment: can you just send me a picture of your own configurations

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368748/android-studio-module-wont-show-up-in-edit-configuration

Comment: If that didn't work, try this step by step guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-an-android-run-debug-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

depending on your version of android studio, check if Power Saver mode is enabled, could be the cause