# Android Studio 3.3 Signed APK Option Missing

Tags: ionic4, signed-apk, android-studio-3.3

I'm trying to publish my Ionic 4 app into Play Store through Android Studio and the option to build to a **signed APK** is missing. I know there are similar questions to mine already asked here, but their answers are directed for previous versions. I have spent many hours searching through websites and I have typed lots of command prompt commands, such as

```
ionic cordova build android
```

and

```
cordova build --release android
```

I went to build and did the signed APK a few times, and it gave me a small window about "required updates."

I agreed, then it restarted, and after I went back to build and the option was missing! I tried installing and reinstalling Android Studio. I want to be able to create a signed APK and publish my app to Play Store. Where is the missing option? Please help me figure out how to turn on this feature in my Android Studio version 3.3.2.

Comment: As Android studio suggest to upgrade ur gradle so did you done that in your app ?

Comment: yes, to version 4.10.1

Comment: Still signed app option disabled ?

Comment: although that's not the latest version

Comment: yes it isn't showing up

Comment: are you able to build and run app on emulator ?

Comment: I didn't test it in the emulator, I used "ionic serve" through visual studio

Comment: and edited it from there

Comment: so try it once is it woking on emulator from your android studio if you will face any issue than solve that after that you can able to create signed APK.

Comment: it won't run because of the error, "Error: Module not specified"

Comment: and the modules drop box is empty other than "<no module>"

Comment: is there a way to get one?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087882/android-studio-run-debug-configuration-error-module-not-specified

Comment: it runs my app in the emulator

Comment: but there is no signed apk, but only an unsigned apk

Comment: i restarted the app, and it worked! I have the option! thx so much. u really r a "code changer," lol!

Comment: Happy to hear that your problem solved. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CodeChanger. Run the emulator, then restart the app. The Signed APK option will appear.