# No deployment menu after clicking 'run' and cant compile to simulate

Tags: android-studio, gradle

My app used to be able to run through the simulation prior to me updating android studio. Now whenever I try to run it, no menus pop up and a task? is performed instead. I have included pictures below of what I feel may be important. I have tried invalidating chaches and rebuilding gradle many times. I feel I may have changes something by accident. Anyone know what I have done or how to fix it?
[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]]

[image: Picture 3]]

[image: Picture 4]]

Answer (score 0):

Any of these might help fix the problem:

1. Move the entire project to a different folder.
2. Upgrade/downgrade Android Studio.
3. Restart your computer.
4. Check your androidmanifest.xml to make sure nothing is wrong in it.
5. Open another project and compile it. Then come back to this project and try again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What should I be looking for in the manifest? Everything seems to look correct.

Comment: Inconsistent naming, incorrect paths. Intellisense should tell you if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Picture 4 suggests that you have not specified the module. Select the module, `app`. It should run fine.

Comment: When I click on that, nothing appears in the drop down box. Just shows 'no module'

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368748/android-studio-module-wont-show-up-in-edit-configuration or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087882/android-studio-run-debug-configuration-error-module-not-specified