# Android Studio: bugs in first build

Tags: android, android-studio, build, configuration, build.gradle

The Run bottun is disable [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owUYk.png),
I tried to add configure but there is no module in add configuration module [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAc59.png),
and when I press **File-> Sync Project with Gradle file** It's just running and running [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj7ec.png)
Thanks!

Comment: this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/29087882/9603922

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this:
[image: Screen]

You're missing build configurations.

Modules:
[image: https://imgur.com/VHz7BXR]

Comment: I have a problem with buils configuration, there is no module in the select box
what can i do?