# How to run kotlin app from android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, firefox, kotlin, firefox-android

I cloned this repo onto my laptop: https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/focus-android

I then opened Android Studio and imported project. (imported the focus-android folder). But the run button right now is grayed out. I tried to edit configurations and launch the `MainAcitvity.kt`. Here were my configuration settings:
https://preview.redd.it/mdyg1vcvcxi41.png?width=1073&format=png&auto=webp&s=bdcf5f6f51d59c9b107b459a0e2fc76dd6db059f

but I cannot select a module and it says `Error: Module not specified` when I try to run it. How exactly do I launch an activity / run firefox focus through an emulator given the github repo?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tuto to create a virtual device: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

PS: I just run the project to see, I did `File > New > Import Project` and it was working, here is a screen of what you should have https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv5NN.png

Comment: Hi, can you walk me through your steps? You cloned the repo, and this created a `focus-android` folder on your laptop, right? Then you opened android studio, and did `File -> New -> Import Project` and clicked the `focus-android` folder or the `focus-android.app` folder?

Comment: When I go to `edit configurations -> Android app` I cannot select a module. It just says `no module` and when I click the drop-down menu, no module is available to be clicked. Screenshot here: https://preview.redd.it/mdyg1vcvcxi41.png?width=1073&format=png&auto=webp&s=bdcf5f6f51d59c9b107b459a0e2fc76dd6db059f (I tried making it so that it launches default activity as well but it still gives an error saying no module specificed)

Comment: have you tried the accepted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087882/android-studio-run-debug-configuration-error-module-not-specified ?

Comment: I'm updating Android Studio right now, I will try it after the update completes. When you imported the project, did you import `foucus-android` or `focus-android/app`? Thanks.

Comment: I imported from `focus-android`

Comment: After you imported `focus-android`, what was your next step? Did you build and then sync the project? Or did you go straight to `edit configurations -> android app`?

Comment: I builded and sync the project with gradle

Comment: thanks, it worked after I updated my andriod studio version and imported the project again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208525/discussion-between-biscuit-and-user2272600).