# how can i create keystore in android studio?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

i'm trying to create keystore by using android studio.

homepage said i should create keystore at Build - Genderate Signed APK..

i've tried to find  Genderate Signed APK but i don't have

there is no  Genderate Signed APK in my android studio.

what should i do in this case???

how can i create keystore?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no Run configuration for your project. You can see it in the top of the screen - **Add configuration**. Click on it and create new Configuration.

then click on the **build**:
[image]

then click on the  **Generate Signed Bundle/APK**:

[image]

After that this window will be shown, select **apk** and click to **next**:

[image]

Below keystore path click on **create new**:

[image]

After clicking on create new, this window will be shown. Now fill the details and select the **path of keystore** and **keystore file name**, Don't forget to add Validity for up to **1000 years**:

[image]

**Note**: Place the keystore file some where safe, this file will be used for building new apks.

Comment: what should i do at  Add configuration can you say detail??

Comment: update your gradle to latest version, it will automatically add the configuration.

Comment: if this does not work look at this: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig

Comment: i'm trying to follow what you link but error said monule not specified
in Module: <no module> how can i resolve?

Comment: Let me clear it. Does you want to configure your project in your question or how to create a keystore in android studio?

Comment: "how can i create keystore in android studio?"  according to your question I have provide you the complete process and tell you first you need to add configuration for this.

Comment: yes if i want to create keystore as you said i have to   Add configuration...

Comment: you got your question answer, In stackoverflow you cannot ask two question in your current question. Ask a new question about add configuration.

Comment: Just in case anyone ran into the issue that @user15322469 did, if you don't have the Android SDK version your project is targeting you will get the 'no-module' error when adding a configuration. See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65882156/4082254

Answer (score 4):

Go to your `JDK/bin` folder. Open a `Command Prompt` there. Run below command in it.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore mykeyname.keystore -alias mykeyalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -dname "O=organization name"
```

Here replace `mykeyname` with whatever name you want for your keystore. Same do for `mykeyalias` and `organization name`. Where organization name is optional parameter.

**Important**

This command prompts you for password for the keystore. Remember that password for future updates of your application in playstore. The keystore contains a single key, valid for 10000 days. The alias is a name that you will use later when signing your app, so remember to take note of the alias.

Answer (score 2):

You have no Run configuration for your project. (You can see it in the top of the screen - "Add configuration..."). Tap on it and create new Configuration. Then you will be able to run and build your project.

Comment: what should i do at Add configuration can you say detail??

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig

Comment: i'm trying to follow what you link but error said monule not specified
in Module: <no module> how can i resolve?

Comment: Select the module from the combobox.

Comment: i mean there is no the other module there is only <no-module>