# How to generate a signed key for my bundle in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, signed

I'm trying to export and upload a key from Android Studio but all the tutorials I've seen instruct you to click on "Build" and then "Generate Signed Bundle or APK" in Android Studio but I don't have that option. [image]

I currently have Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line and [create a JKS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66981453/how-can-i-create-keystore-in-android-studio) into an app folder.

be sure you use last version of [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)

```
android {
...
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias 'name your choosen'
        keyPassword 'pass'
        storeFile file('key.jks')
        storePassword 'pass'
    }
}
```